# jquery vertical menu collapsing issue

Tags: jquery, navigation

First of all I am a complete started in jquery and what I need is to modify script. Now I have submenu, when I open it and open link, it collapses, what I want is to when I open submenu item link, submenu would still be opened when page reload, is it possible

here is link to menu script I am using http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/vertical-accordion-menu-using-jquery-css3

```
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
        //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: p.s
I tryed $(this).attr("class","active"); but it works only till page refreshes

Comment: you need to work with cookies to keep it open. [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: another way would be to use hashes. [example](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-advanced/)

Comment: @Raimonds seems not to be satisfied with any response

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to add and remove classes

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#accordian").each(function(position){
            var container = $(this);
            var containerId = container.attr("id");
            if (! containerId){
                  container.attr("id", position);
                  containerId = position; 
            }
            if ($.cookie('expanded_'+ containerId) == 'true')
                container.addClass("expanded");
        });
        $("#accordian h3").click(function(){
            //slide up all the link lists
            var title = $(this);
            var container = title.closest("div");
            var containerId = container.attr("id");

            if (container.hasClass("expanded")){
                container.children("ul").slideUp();
                container.removeClass("expanded");
                $.cookie('expanded_'+ containerId,'false')
            } else {
                container.children("ul").slideDown();
                container.addClass("expanded");
                $.cookie('expanded_'+ containerId,'true')
            }    
        })
    })
```

The page reload problem is with the cookies http://lineadecodigo.com/jquery/usando-cookies-con-jquery/

Also, I would suggest to do "accordian" a class instead of a ID

Comment: this is not an answer to the page-reload problem

Comment: @redreggae do yo see anything on the answer that deserves the negative vote ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies, however I would advise against using them for something this simple.

Simply add a hash tag to the URL and make the menu react to it.

When your click event fires, fire setHash with a string like this: setHash("task")

```
function setHash(str)
{
    try
    {
        window.location.hash=str;
    }
    catch(err){/*if you want error reporting add it here*/}
}
```

Then check it with this:

```
if(window.location.hash == something)
{
    //open menu here
}
```

I haven't added the code for the accordion, but you should have access to its API. **Also be aware that jQueryUI has an accordion with all functions broken out** :)

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Using the jQueryUI accordion may be easier as a beginner since much of the work has been done for you.

Comment: Also be aware of the new cookie EU rules if it applies or has interest. http://www.theeucookielaw.com/ if you swing that way :)